# android deserialize object?

Tags: android, android-intent

how to deserialize this type:

```
public Intent putExtra(String name, Serializable value)
```

example:

```
 intent.putExtra("activityToPass", GoToThisActivity.class);
 ???
 getIntent().getExtras.getSerializable("activityToPass");
```

how to do this please;

please help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to pass a custom object from one activity to the other, first you must have your custom object's class to implement `java.io.Serializable`:

```
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    public SomeObject (final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    [...]
}

final SomeObject myExtra = new SomeObject("any name");
```

Then you can add this myExtra to the intent with which you call your new `Activity`:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoToThisActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("serializedExtra", myExtra);
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside your `GoToThisActivity` class' `onCreate` method you can extract this extra as:

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("serializedExtra"))
    final SomeObject myExtra= (SomeObject)intent.
        getSerializableExtra("serializedExtra");
    [...]
}
```

And now you have your custom object in your new activity.

**Update 1:** Passing a class to an other activity with `Intent` 
If you want to pass a `Class` instance to an intent:

```
intent.putExtra("classExtra", GoToThisActivity.class);
```

and to deserialize it in the other activity:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("classExtra"))
{
    final Class<?> classExtra= (Class<?>)intent.
        getSerializableExtra("classExtra");
    [...]
}
```

**Update 2:**
When deserializing an array of custom objects, you have to make sure, that the elements in that array implement the `Serializable` interface.

To stay at your sample:

```
public class ButtonPick implements Serializable
{
    public static final ButtonPick EDIT = new ButtonPick();
    public static final ButtonPick DELETE = new ButtonPick();
}
```

You put the extra in the `Intent`:

```
intent.putExtra("buttonPicks", new ButtonPick[]
    {ButtonPick.DELETE,ButtonPick.EDIT});
```

And inside the other activity deserialize it:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("buttonPicks"))
{
    final Object[] buttonPicks= (Object[])intent.
        getSerializableExtra("buttonPicks");
        [...]
}
```

You MUST cast the array as `Object[]` regardless to the original being `ButtonPicks[]`.
The elements inside the array have their proper type, so inside are the

> { ButtonPicks.EDIT, ButtonPicks.DELETE }

members.
You need to cast them individually.

Comment: what about passing a class through serializable?, i dont want to create any more custom objects. example: intent.putExtra("activityToPass", GoToThisActivity.class), since for java, GoToThisActivity.class is serializable! thanks.

Comment: sorry, i've just jumped over that part by mistake, but please see my update for passing a class.

Comment: will try it master rekaszeru!

Comment: last one rekaszeru sensei, how deserialize this, so far no luck: intent.putExtra("buttonPicks", new ButtonPick[]{ButtonPick.DELETE,ButtonPick.EDIT} ); //where ButtonPick is an Enum. Do I need to create a custom object for this?

Comment: i've posted a new update with a sample on how to deserialize arrays, i hope it will work for you.

Comment: sensei rekaszeru provided all my questions about the laws of the world, greatly appreciated indeed!

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a headache